# What is *actually* happening within this stale closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I feel as though my knowledge with closures is *almost* there, but I'm struggling to grasp exactly why this first code snippet logs 0 (is a stale closure) however, the second code snippet works and logs the updated value ..

Is this some kind of reference issue?

In the first example, are we not tracking the reference of count and only assigning its initial value to message?

By moving the message variable inside of the log function are we somehow telling JS to track the reference of the count value?

```js
function createIncrement() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  let message = count;
  function log() {
    console.log(message);
  }

  return [increment, log];
}

const [increment, log] = createIncrement();

increment();
log();

// this will log 0
```

```js
function createIncrement() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  function log() {
    let message = count;
    console.log(message);
  }

  return [increment, log];
}

const [increment, log] = createIncrement();

increment();
log();

// this will log 1
```

Comment: "*In the first example, are we not tracking the reference of count and only assigning its initial value to message?*" - yes. The closure is tracking the reference of `message`, which only has the initial value of `count` but doesn't get updated by the `log` closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the first example, are we not tracking the reference of count and only assigning its initial value to message?
> By moving the message variable inside of the log function are we somehow telling JS to track the reference of the count value?

This is the thing you're struggling with. Let's try to decompose what happens there.

At its core, it's just about this:

```js
let count = 0;
let message = count;
console.log(message);
count++; // it's exactly the same as count = count + 1;
console.log(message); // still prints 0
```

This has nothing to do with closures, and everything to do about numbers being immutable values. When we increment `count` we are assigning to the variable a new instance of a number with the value 1.
`message` is still pointing to the old instance (value, in this case it's the same), so the log is going to print the same old value.

If I understand your misunderstanding correctly (!) you're picturing that `count` is a container in which you can insert a numeric value, which is slightly wrong.

It is a pointer to a numeric and immutable value, that sits in memory somewhere. When you do `message = count` you ensure message and count are pointing to the same memory address, that contains a `0`.

When you write `count++`, you are allocating a new number in memory, somewhere, for the number 1, and `count` now points to the new object. `message` is unaffected by this operation. **This is the crucial bit that I think is not crystal clear**.

In your second example, `message` is reassigned every time you log, so it will always hold a reference to the correct value.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: I just edited the answer to better explain the memory addressing.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function createIncrement() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  let message=`Count is ${count}`;
  function log() {
    console.log(message);
  }

  return [increment, log];
}

const [increment, log] = createIncrement();

increment();
increment();
increment();
log();

// this will log 0
```

```js
function createIncrement() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  function log() {
    let message = count;
    console.log(message);
  }

  return [increment, log];
}

const [increment, log] = createIncrement();

increment();
log();

// this will log 1
```

```js
function createIncrement() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  function log() {
    let message = count;
    console.log(message);
  }

  return [increment, log];
}

const [increment, log] = createIncrement();

increment();
log();

// this will log 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question